# Disabling Asp.Net Auto Naming

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to disable the ASP.Net auto-naming?

**For instance**: When I have a control on my page that sits inside a masterpage instead of being named

`theLabel`

it is renamed to

`ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_clist0_rptSelected_ctl05_theLabel`

This is the behavior I don't want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're lucky enough to be able to target ASP.NET 4.0...

In your page directive, set `ClientIDMOde="Static"`.  This will emit ID's exactly as you have them in your controls.

So if you have:

```
<asp:Label ID="example" runat="server" />
```

It will emit this clean ID:

```
<span id="example">something...</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a common headache with ASP.NET.  If ASP.NET 4 is an option for you, you can use the new ClientID functionality to customize the naming convention.

More information, courtesy of The Gu:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [ASP.NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) then yes you can.

Otherwise, it's difficult. If you want the client id in javascript you can do something like this::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DoSomething(){
        alert('<%= Control.ClientID %>');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is what I normally do, but I a whole lot of JS in .js files, that I'd like to keep there.  So I can't really use the gator tags. +1 tho, this will help someone in the future...