# CSS Javascript Help needed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a project where I can only change the css to adjust anything on the site. I have a table which has js calling the image which is 125px x 125px and has a style hardcoded into the html to scale image to 125px × 125px (scaled to 66px × 95px). What I am looking for is to at least square it up to 66px x 66px? `style="height:95px;width:66px;border-width:0px;"` The issue I am having is the id ctl00_MainCartDisplay_Image_21313_208_0 is unique to the product being called, so when we tried

```
#ctl00_MainCartDisplay_Image_21313_208_0 img {height:50 !important;}
```

worked great, remove `_21313_208_0` and now nothing? Any help would be great, the Code below and Thanks

`style="height:95px;width:66px;border-width:0px;"`

```
 <table class="SCNVSCProductSubTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0"       style="width:200px;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" style="width:66px;"><input type="image"
    name="ctl00$MainCartDisplay$Image_21313_208_0"
    id="ctl00_MainCartDisplay_Image_21313_208_0" src="../art/NoImage66x95.jpg"
    onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
    WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainCartDisplay$Image_21313_208_0&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;ProductDetail.aspx?CatalogueID=208&amp;ProductID=21313&quot;, false, false))" style="height:95px;width:66px;border-width:0px;" />
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Java != Javascript, and please clean up your question first, you are posting as if we need some help

Comment: Please take a deep breath first before posting ur question....once u r back in mortal world, explain ur problem calmly then....meanwhile, i wud edit ur post :p

Comment: There is my code need the image to be set at 66X66px need help with some CSS code to do it with. Sorry if I was clear as mud.

Comment: Based on `id`s it's generated by server side. Look's like ASP.NET, so if you have multiple images you could add css class or client id.

Comment: @Givi yes it is asp.net sorry for the title. Hey always seem to find my answer here by searching could not on this. Could you possible show me an example? Thanks

Comment: Look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108887/Client-Ids-Generation-with-ASP-NET-4-0)

Comment: Look at [Disabling Asp.Net Auto Naming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548560/disabling-asp-net-auto-naming) and this one too [Control.ClientID Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selectors to select the elements where the `id` begins with a specific string. Doesn't work for IE8 and below though.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings

#### CSS

```
[id^="ctl00_MainCartDisplay_Image"] {
  height:50 !important;
}
```